# JMeter - Function not evaluated in remote server

Tags: jmeter

I'm using some JMeter's functions in my HTTP request using (version 3.1). In particular I'm using *__time()* function and it works fine if I execute the test plan in local machine, either using CLI or GUI, but when I connect to remote JMeter in server mode (same version) the function are not evaluated and my HTTP request contains the function verbatim.

I created a test plan named MyHTTPTest.jmx wich sends HTTP request and contains this function in body: `${__time(YMDHMS)}`.

If I execute the test in local machine:

```
bin/jmeter.sh -n -t MyHTTPTest.jmx
```

my request contains *20161229-123355* and it works as expected.

If I execute the test plan using remote servers, for example:

```
remote-server: bin/jmeter.sh -s
local-server: bin/jmeter.sh -n -R remote-server -t MyHTTPTest.jmx
```

my request contains *${__time(YMDHMS)}* verbatim and time function is not evalueted.

I tried other functions and I created *user defined variable* initialized with function value but the problem persist.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: start the Jmeter in `server mode` in the `remote-server`. Instead of `bin/jmeter.sh -s` (where -s is for system property), run the command as follows `bin/jmeter-server.sh`

Comment: -S is for system property, -s is for server. Anyway, I have 15 remote servers and my setup works, I have problems only with function evaluation in remote servers.